# Ignoring non-visible class specified via --classlist or --testclass in Randoop?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests, randoop

I am trying to run a class in Randoop for automatic Test case Generation , My randoop is installed in `/home/niteshb/Music/randoop-3.0.8`  and my Java class is in `/home/niteshb/Tests.class` and I was trying to execute this with command

```
 java -ea -classpath /home/niteshb/Music/randoop-3.0.8/randoop-all-3.0.8.jar:/home/niteshb randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=Tests
```

and I am getting error as

```
policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@3d82c5f3
policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@3d82c5f3
Ignoring non-visible class Tests specified via --classlist or --testclass.
No classes to test


Exiting Randoop.
```

Dont know what is the exact issue , stucked here literally .. can someone help me with this :-

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information to reproduce your problem (for example, the `Tests.java` file), but perhaps the problem is that the `Tests` class is not public.  Try adding `public` to the class declaration.